# Filebeat - Non json to Json with custom tags

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat

My existing application is currently logging the logs (its a shell script)

as below. It is basically logging it as single log line - non json.

TIME=25-Dec 03:30:06 565 PM MST ERROR MyFunction - Environment : Auth fail

I would like to ship these logs using Filebeat but there is requirement to

change this to json format with some additional keys.

"app" : "abcd"
"trkid" : "xyz"

How can i configure the filebeat to send the logs in this format.

Note: Rewriting the existing application to produce json logs is not an option.

Regards

Comment: You're gonna have to implement parsing of your logs in logstash. Take a look at Grok filter.

Comment: The way its setup is , we only have filebeat in our server ; so any changes and configuration can be done in the filebeat in our server

Comment: As far as I know You can't do this by filebeat. You can change your script to write logs in json or you can use some extra utility on your server to read this output and transform it to json.